# wordpress curl 6 Could not resolve host http_request_failed error

Tags: help

I am running a website through tor, but there are two errors in the site health item as above.
Is there a solution?

Comment: You'll need to post more details if you want help. How did you set up your onion service (what web server are you using, how are you running wordpress, etc)? Where exactly do you see these errors, and what details do they give you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to post some more detailed logs, but basically - it happens in WP and Drupal and other CMS systems - it's the DNS problem. You need to enable host binding in Tor config and transparent proxy as well, and - important moment - you need to make Tor's resolver available system-wide. I'm using local BIND setup with all the dot-onion zone resolving forwarded to Tor's DNSPort